# Homogeneous linear ODEs with time-dependent coefficient matrix, optimalisation of NDSolve algorithm

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to ask for advice on the following (probably not too complicated) problem:

I have a linear system of ODEs of the following form:

$$
\dot{X}(t) = M(t)X(t)
$$

where $ X(t) $ is a vector, $ M(t) $ is a matrix of $ n \times n $ size. The algorithm for the equations itself is:

```
n = 2 (1 + 2*size)^2;
X[t_] = Table[xi[i, t], {i, 1, n}];
X0 = Table[0, {n}];
X0[[Round[n/2]]] = 1;
diffEq = Table[
   X'[t][[i]] == -0.5 I*(Evomatrix[t].X[t])[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
initialCond = Table[X[0][[i]] == X0[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
sol = NDSolve[{Join[diffEq, initialCond]}, X[t], {t, 0, 1},
  Method -> "BDF",
  PrecisionGoal -> 0, AccuracyGoal -> 0, MaxStepSize -> 0.00001]

Plot[Abs[Evaluate[Table[xi[i, t] /. sol, {i, 1, 2}]]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[Abs[xi[1, t] /. sol]^2 + Abs[xi[2, t] /. sol]^2 ], {t, 
  0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which works perfectly with only two variable, but does not finish running even under an hour with 18 variables.

The time-dependent matrix itself is defined in a rather complicated way, also involving matrix-inversion (I tried using [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) but I did not notice any difference). Even still, the matrix is evaluated for concrete values in about a second, so I imagine that with proper stepsize it should work out. Anyway here are the codes:

```
gamma = -0.005;
omega = 1;
size = 0;
eltolas = 200;
Szorz[elso_, masod_] := 
 Exp[-0.5 (Abs[elso])^2 - 0.5 (Abs[masod])^2 + Conjugate[elso]*masod ]
```

Here "size" is the important (integer) parameter. With 0, the algorithm runs quickly, but if it is 1, I already have a problem.

```
l := Sqrt[Pi]*(Mod[y - 1, 1 + 2*size] - size + Re[eltolas]);
m := Sqrt[Pi]*Floor[(y - 1)/(1 + 2*size) - size + Im[eltolas]];
s := Sqrt[Pi]*(Mod[x - 1, 1 + 2*size] - size + Re[eltolas]);
p := Sqrt[Pi]*Floor[(x - 1)/(1 + 2*size) - size + Im[eltolas]];
BRAalfaP[t_] := gamma + (l + I*m - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
KETalfaP[t_] := gamma + (s + I*p - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
BRAalfaN[t_] := -gamma + (l + I*m + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
KETalfaN[t_] := -gamma + (s + I*p + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
BRAGammaP[t_] := gamma*Im[l + I*m - (l + I*m - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];
KETGammaP[t_] := gamma*Im[s + I*p - (s + I*p - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];
BRAGammaN[t_] := -gamma*
   Im[l + I*m - (l + I*m + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];


KETGammaN[t_] := -gamma*
      Im[s + I*p - (s + I*p + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]]

PP[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaP[t], KETalfaP[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaP[t] - BRAGammaP[t])] , {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

NN[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaN[t], KETalfaN[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaN[t] - BRAGammaN[t])] , {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

PN[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaP[t], KETalfaN[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaN[t] - BRAGammaP[t])] , {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

NP[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaN[t], KETalfaP[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaP[t] - BRAGammaN[t])] , {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

PtoN[t_] := Inverse[PP[t]].PN[t];
NtoP[t_] := Inverse[NN[t]].NP[t]
```

And finally, I define the matrix through [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html). I can't copy&paste it here, so I give it as a picture:
[image]

My question is, how could I make this algorithm run in a reasonably short time with the "size" parameter being larger than 0?

Comment: I can not understand from the figure how the matrix is arranged. This is true `m0 = SparseArray[{}, {(1 + 2 size)^2, (1 + 2 size)^2}];
Evomatrix[t_] := ArrayFlatten[{{m0, PtoN[t]}, {NtoP[t], m0}}];`?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the correct formula, sorry for the ambiguity above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the fomal solution of the matrix equation and the numerical integration scheme of 1-8 order. First, write a simple code to compare with `NDSolve`. This piece of code works for `size = 0,1,2...` (note, I changed the definition of the matrix `Evomatrix[t]`):

```
size = 0; n = 2 (1 + 2*size)^2;

initialCond = X == X0 /. t -> 0;
gamma = -0.005;
omega = 1;
eltolas = 200;
Szorz[elso_, masod_] := 
 Exp[-0.5 (Abs[elso])^2 - 0.5 (Abs[masod])^2 + Conjugate[elso]*masod]
l := Sqrt[Pi]*(Mod[y - 1, 1 + 2*size] - size + Re[eltolas]);
m := Sqrt[Pi]*Floor[(y - 1)/(1 + 2*size) - size + Im[eltolas]];
s := Sqrt[Pi]*(Mod[x - 1, 1 + 2*size] - size + Re[eltolas]);
p := Sqrt[Pi]*Floor[(x - 1)/(1 + 2*size) - size + Im[eltolas]];
BRAalfaP[t_] := gamma + (l + I*m - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
KETalfaP[t_] := gamma + (s + I*p - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
BRAalfaN[t_] := -gamma + (l + I*m + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
KETalfaN[t_] := -gamma + (s + I*p + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t];
BRAGammaP[t_] := gamma*Im[l + I*m - (l + I*m - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];
KETGammaP[t_] := gamma*Im[s + I*p - (s + I*p - gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];
BRAGammaN[t_] := -gamma*
   Im[l + I*m - (l + I*m + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]];


KETGammaN[t_] := -gamma*Im[s + I*p - (s + I*p + gamma) Exp[-I*omega*t]]

PP[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaP[t], KETalfaP[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaP[t] - BRAGammaP[t])], {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

NN[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaN[t], KETalfaN[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaN[t] - BRAGammaN[t])], {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

PN[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaP[t], KETalfaN[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaN[t] - BRAGammaP[t])], {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

NP[t_] := 
  Table[Szorz[BRAalfaN[t], KETalfaP[t]]*
    Exp[I*(KETGammaP[t] - BRAGammaN[t])], {x, (1 + 
       2 size)^2}, {y, (1 + 2 size)^2}];

PtoN[t_] := Inverse[PP[t]].PN[t];
NtoP[t_] := Inverse[NN[t]].NP[t];
m0 = SparseArray[{}, {(1 + 2 size)^2, (1 + 2 size)^2}];
Evomatrix[t_] := -0.5 I*ArrayFlatten[{{m0, PtoN[t]}, {NtoP[t], m0}}];
Evomatrix[2] // MatrixForm

tau = .001; X = Table[x[i][t], {t, 0, 1, tau}, {i, n}];
Table[X[[1, i]] = 0, {i, n}];
X[[1, Round[n/2]]] = 1;
T = Table[t, {t, 0, 1, tau}];
Do[X[[k]] = MatrixExp[tau Evomatrix[tau (k - 1/2)], X[[k - 1]]];, {k, 2, Length[X]}]
```

Compare the solution with `NDSolve[]`:

```
    X1[t_] = Table[xi[i, t], {i, 1, n}];
    X0 = Table[0, {n}];
    X0[[Round[n/2]]] = 1;
    diffEq = Table[X1'[t][[i]] == (Evomatrix[t].X1[t])[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
    initialCond = Table[X1[0][[i]] == X0[[i]], {i, 1, n}];
    sol = NDSolve[{Join[diffEq, initialCond]}, X1[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
       Method -> "BDF", MaxStepSize -> tau];
Table[Show[Plot[Abs[xi[i, t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{T, Abs[Chop[Flatten[X[[All, i]]]]]}], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange]], {i, 2}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We see that there are slight differences, but the code can be used for `size = 1`:
[image: Figure 2]

For `size=2` and `tau=.01` it takes 24 sec on my ASUS 
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working much more quickly with your algorithm.

Comment: @Gomboc You're welcome. What is the maximum system size?